# how to redirect url before laravel check it in its web.php?

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect, routes

i want to make a redirect panel and add some urls to it, if this urls are called(requested) it should redirect to new url before checking it in routes ->web.php file. i used a middleware for this and added the middleware to middlewares list in kernel but it doesn't work for some urls,
what is the best solution?

> kernel file

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUrlMiddleware::class,

    ];
```

last middleware is the middleware that i created

> CheckUrlMiddleware file

```
class CheckUrlMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        
        $url = urldecode($request->root().Request::getRequestUri());
        
        $url = Redirect_custom_url::where('old' , $url)->first();
        
        if ($url != null) {
            
            return Redirect::to($url->new);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to allow a redirect to a possibly undefined url route? im just curious

Comment: i want to redirect it to a defined url, i had a website and it was written with pure php , i rebulid it using laravel, but the old website had some routes that i dont have in the new website so they return 404 and its bad for seo, i need to redirect that urls to the urls in my new website

Comment: you can use your web server to redirect your application's routes to a different website's routes [this](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-redirect-urls-with-nginx/) may help if you're using nginx